# how to pause a video file played using videosourceplayer

Tags: c#, aforge, video-player

I am playing a videofile(.wmv)using videosourceplayer .I am able to stop videoplayer but when i start it ,it starts from the beginning but not from the current frame.How can i achieve the pause and resume playback of the video

Comment: Are you using `VideoSourcePlayer` class from AForge.NET framework? You would need `Pause` and `Resume` methods which it doesn't seem to have based on its [documentation](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/add76389-ee37-d3a9-25e3-0bfee93e05cd.htm).

Comment: yes,i am using aforge.net framework and videosourceplayer class.And i didnot get any such methods like pause or resume for use with videosourceplayer..is there any way to get this into work using videosourceplayer class

Comment: I strongly doubt, it is possible without modifying `VideoSourcePlayer`.  There's even [an open issue](https://code.google.com/p/aforge/issues/detail?id=206) asking for this feature. I've added some tags to your question, so maybe somebody will see it, who has more experience with the control.

Comment: @DamirArh Thank you.Now since it seems there isn't any method in videosource documentation  to pause a video,i would like to put this into affect using certain logic which i am not sure of right now but I am thinking of stopping the video,keep track of the last frame and then play the video from that frame number.Is there any way to start the videosource directly from a specified frame number instead of starting the video from the beginning,thanks in advance.

Comment: @Amysegenuelle I don't think you'll be able to achieve that without modifying the [library source](https://code.google.com/p/aforge/source/browse/trunk/Sources/), but I could be wrong.