# Failed to take photo with the webcam using the library AForge

Tags: c#, winforms, aforge

I am making use of the `AForge` class library.

From this library I am using `VideoSourcePlayer` to take photos with the webcam.

My purpose is to create a function that allows the user to photograph images to establish them as company logo.
Not only can you choose images from the computer, but you can also capture images from the outside through the camera, since you may only want to transfer a logo of a physical support (paper) to the program.

As commented earlier in SO, ([how to pause a video file played using videosourceplayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27738369/how-to-pause-a-video-file-played-using-videosourceplayer)), `VideoSourcePlayer` does not have a `Pause` method or any function that allows to freeze the image.

Yes, it is true that it has the `GetCurrentFrame()` method, but that only gets a `Bitmap` from the current frame that must be passed to a `PictureBox`.

But I want that when the user clicks the button `Capture` the image of the `VideoSourcePlayer` simulate being frozen, and when the user presses the `Delete` button because he did not like the photo, then the image stops being frozen and recovers its movement.

Logic is like pausing or playing a video.

Well, there's no method for it, so I decided to look for another way to get this, and ...

If a picture is taken, use a `PictureBox` that contains the last frame and that is displayed on the `VideoSourcePlayer`, but if it is deleted, then the `PictureBox` is removed and the `VideoSourcePlayer` is returned with video.

```
 private readonly Bitmap EmptyBitmap;

 private void CaptureBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      Bitmap bitmap = this.VideoSource.GetCurrentVideoFrame();

      ShowTakedFrame(bitmap, false);
 }

 private void ShowTakedFrame(Bitmap Frame, bool remove)
 {
       var picture = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
           picture.Size = this.VideoSource.Size;
           picture.Location = this.VideoSource.Location;

           if (!remove)
           {
                this.VideoSource.Stop();
                picture.Image = Frame;
                this.Controls.Remove(VideoSource);
                this.Controls.Add(picture);
           }
           else
           {
                this.Controls.Remove(picture);
                this.Controls.Add(VideoSource);
                this.VideoSource.VideoSource = this.CaptureDevice;
                this.VideoSource.Start();
           }
 }

 private void DeleteBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      ShowTakedFrame(EmptyBitmap, true);
 }
```

My problem is that when capturing the photo, the image is a few seconds after the moment when you press the `Capture` button and when you delete the captured image, using the `Delete` button, the video of the `VideoSourcePlayer` is frozen.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you remove the `PictureBox` and add the `VideoSourcePlayer`, it creates a new object, that is, one that does not have the configuration properties of the previous one. My recommendation is that you create the capture in a different form.